# How to make auth token/header more accessible in flask

Tags: authentication, flask, flask-login

I know that global variables are not thread safe in flask, but at the same time, I don't want to have to cascade the token through a bunch of methods whenever the API receives a request in order to pass a bearer token to some other service request.

What is the best way to make the auth token accessible to other methods in the app? Sort of in the same way `curent_user` from `flask_login` is accessible. Perhaps adding it the the user's session somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In a previous life I worked on an internal flask framework within a company that used OAuth/tokens as the standard.  What I found worked pretty well was implementing a custom Request Loader login using Flask Login:

https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class

Or alternatively using the Authorization header if that's how your apps are setup:

https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-using-authorization-header

Comment: Thanks @Mike Sandford. After creating the custom request loader, I can just import it from `flask_login`?